# ng-pattern gives "Lexer Error"?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

As an attribute of an input element I have:

```
ng-pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"
```

Whats wrong this this expression?

I get this error:

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$].
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to add `/` before `^` and after the `$` sign.

**E.g.**

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

By default angularjs wraps regular expression with `^` and `$` symbols. Remove those.

<sub>Fragment from code:</sub>

```
var f, g = d.ngPattern || d.pattern;
d.$observe("pattern", function(a) {
     C(a) && 0 < a.length && (a = new RegExp("^" + a + "$"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put your regex in code, rather in html:

In controller:

```
function SomeController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.regex = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/.source;
}
```

In html (assuming your controller is aliased as "ctrl"):

```
ng-pattern="ctrl.regex"
```

Comment: Please explain why "vm" is always used as an alias for the controller. Does it mean "View Model"?

Comment: @tarekahf https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing problem similar to :
Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 7-7 [#] in expression [consts.#Contact]

With:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('XXController',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $q, XXService, configuration, constants) {

    $scope.consts = constants.constants;
    //...
});
```

**constants_en.json:**

```
{

 "#Contact":"Contact Details",
...

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="contact">{{ consts.#Contact }} </label>
```

**Solution :** Use following in HTML:

```
<label for="customer">{{ consts['#Contact'] }}</label>
```